# Rstudio: Solving an equation using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Equation: 1 + 2/3 + (2/3 * 4/5) + (2/3 * 4/5 * 6/7) +...+ (2/3 * 4/5 *...* 38/39)

Been going around in circles trying to solve this equation in Rstudio and would really appreciate it if someone could help me or point me in a direction to solve this equation. Thank you :)

Language: R (base packages); Interface: RStudio

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Remember that stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Apologies for that, only getting to look at the comments now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `seq` function to build your fractions and then use `prod` to get the product of each sequence.

```
##define first element as 1
res=1

##for loop to get fractions and calculate product
for(i in 1:19){
  res=c(res,prod(seq(2,i*2,2)/seq(3,i*2+1,2)))
}

##sum all elements
sum(res)
```

[1] 6.976346

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, just a quick question to you though. res being the object that is equal to 1, why does the command in the loop equal to res aswell? Are they dependent on each other? Im new to use R and its my first language that im working with so im just trying to understand the reasoning behind that.

Comment: That part in the for loop concatenates each new value in the sequence, it doesn't overwrite it but rather adds the next value to the existing vector